# Cannot setup ssh server

Tags: ssh, sshd, ufw

I'm trying to setup my ssh server at home, but cannot make it work yet.

1. I already forwarded the IP inside the router website.
2. I have an external IP. I can access to my router's config using it.
3. I pointed the ssh server config to the internal IP I am doing the port forwarding to
4. I can connect using that port both with my local ip, and with the LAN ip.
5. set ufw to allow all connections on that port

`tcpdump` shows packets coming. Nothing more.

What am I missing?

sshd config

```
Port 3022
#AddressFamily any
ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
```

ufw

```
root@f1:/home/blas# ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
3022                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
3022 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

ssh client

```
blas@f1:~$ ssh -vvv -p 3022 <EXTERNAL IP>
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/blas/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "<EXTERNAL IP>" port 3022
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to <EXTERNAL IP> [<EXTERNAL IP>] port 3022.
ssh: connect to host <EXTERNAL IP> port 3022: Connection timed out
```

tcpdump

```
listening on wlx7cdd90d820e0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
20:17:22.471642 IP f1.44176 > <><><>.3022: Flags [S], seq 1768782276, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 4260014729 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
    0x0000:  4500 003c 84dc 4000 4006 8943 c0a8 000a  E..<..@.@..C....
    0x0010:  50a2 1b48 ac90 0bce 696d 79c4 0000 0000  P..H....imy.....
    0x0020:  a002 7210 654e 0000 0204 05b4 0402 080a  ..r.eN..........
    0x0030:  fdea aa89 0000 0000 0103 0307            ............
20:17:23.467625 IP f1.44176 > <><><>.3022: Flags [S], seq 1768782276, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 4260015750 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
    0x0000:  4500 003c 84dd 4000 4006 8942 c0a8 000a  E..<..@.@..B....
    0x0010:  50a2 1b48 ac90 0bce 696d 79c4 0000 0000  P..H....imy.....
    0x0020:  a002 7210 6151 0000 0204 05b4 0402 080a  ..r.aQ..........
    0x0030:  fdea ae86 0000 0000 0103 0307            ............
20:17:25.503632 IP f1.44176 > <><><>.3022: Flags [S], seq 1768782276, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 4260017766 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
    0x0000:  4500 003c 84de 4000 4006 8941 c0a8 000a  E..<..@.@..A....
    0x0010:  50a2 1b48 ac90 0bce 696d 79c4 0000 0000  P..H....imy.....
    0x0020:  a002 7210 5971 0000 0204 05b4 0402 080a  ..r.Yq..........
    0x0030:  fdea b666 0000 0000 0103 0307            ...f........
20:17:29.519614 IP f1.44176 > <><><>.3022: Flags [S], seq 1768782276, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 4260021798 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
    0x0000:  4500 003c 84df 4000 4006 8940 c0a8 000a  E..<..@.@..@....
    0x0010:  50a2 1b48 ac90 0bce 696d 79c4 0000 0000  P..H....imy.....
    0x0020:  a002 7210 49b1 0000 0204 05b4 0402 080a  ..r.I...........
    0x0030:  fdea c626 0000 0000 0103 0307            ...&........
```

Comment: As what user are you trying to connect via ssh? Is there an `AllowUsers` line in your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` including that user?

Comment: Hi. There is not. But, as stated in point 4. I am able to connect when changing the IP to 127.0.0.1, or to the one of my LAN. It's actually timing out, and not failing authentication.